# jQuery Modal Overlaying Whole Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a jQuery Dialog defined as such:

```
$(function ()
    {
        $("#addDocumentModal").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 475
        });

        //allow asp.net button clicks
        $("#addDocumentModal").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    });
```

The last line is designed to allow ASP.NET button clicks to still process, however the issue I'm running into is when I have that line in the background image from the UI style (tried a couple of different ones - all from http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) covers over the dialog so you can't do anything. Taking that line out allows the dialog to show as expected, but then the button doesn't work.

One note, I also tried it with $(document).ready() (instead of just $(function()) and that didn't change anything.

Any suggestions? I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Jquery(jquery.UI) dumps few inlune styles automatically when you make it as modal. Here is the solution:

Download jquery.ui style sheet and include the styles in your solution to customize it and refer to the downloaded:(link below)

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Inside this style sheet - find "ui-front" class.

Change/Add z-index to 500 or keep changing until you acheive what you need.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to push the parent of the div, push the dialog into the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addDocumentModal").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 475
    }).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); //allow asp.net button clicks
});
```

If that doesn't work, look at the CSS that the modal div is set to on z-index.  Make sure it is lower than the dialog.

Comment: I tried this but no luck - the background still overlays everything. I wasn't entirely sure what you meant about the z-index comment, but I tried it on the main div (addDocumentModal) and in the JS before the .parent() call (i.e }).css('z-index', 10000).parent() ...) but that didn't change anything. I saw where a z-index was applied via the ui-front class and turning it off allows my physical div to show up (and the ASP.NET button works), but the modal title and close button are still hidden behind the background overlay image.